# doParallel foreach scoping issue: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function

Tags: r, timer, foreach, parallel-processing, polling

I want to execute a [`tclTaskSchedule`](http://www.inside-r.org/node/75491) timer (from the `tcltk2` package) inside each [`doParallel`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/foreach/docs/foreach) thread. However, the following minimal code

```
library(doParallel)

n <- detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(n, outfile="out.log")
registerDoParallel(cl)

testfn <- function() print(paste("hello from", i))
foreach(i=1:n, .packages = c("tcltk", "tcltk2"), .verbose = T) %dopar% {
    tclTaskSchedule(1000, testfn(), id = paste0("task", i), redo = 10)
}

stopCluster(cl)
```

results in the error (printed *not* in the console, but in `out.log`)

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "testfn"
```

However, from the `.verbose = T` argument, I can see from the console that `testfn` *is* getting exported:

```
automatically exporting the following variables from the local environment:
  testfn
```

Indeed, calling `foreach` with `.export = "testfn"` results in the same error.

So what's going wrong?

---

(*Why do I want to do this?* In the end, I want to [poll](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_%28computer_science%29) a number of data sources at regular time intervals asynchronously, and where each data source has its own particular polling interval)

Comment: I believe the problem is not so much `dopar`, but `tclTaskSchedule` which does some internal magic with environments. If you put just `print(testfn)` in the `foreach` loop, you'll see that the function is defined on the workers. However, somehow `tclTaskSchedule` looks for it in the wrong environment. I tried some things, but couldn't find a way to fix this. PS: If you run the loop without parallelization, you'll see that you also have a problem with lazy evaluation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Roland that the problem is in the way that `tclTaskSchedule` evaluates its arguments.  My solution isn't pretty, but I got it to work by exporting `testfn` using `clusterExport` and assigning `i` to the worker's global environment in the foreach loop:

```
testfn <- function() print(paste("hello from", i))
clusterExport(cl, "testfn")

foreach(i=1:n, .packages = c("tcltk", "tcltk2"), .verbose = F) %dopar% {
    i <<- i
    tclTaskSchedule(1000, testfn(), id = paste0("task", i), redo = 10)
}
```

I would probably also pass `.noexport="testfn"` to foreach, but it isn't really necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You're also going to discover another problem, even without `tclTaskSchedule`:
`print` statements within a *parallelized* `foreach` loop **will not output** to an interactive session:

From [a blog post](http://www.r-bloggers.com/monitoring-progress-inside-a-foreach-loop/):

> One problem with foreach is that it creates new RScript instances for each iteration of the loop, which prevents status messages from being logged to the console output.

A work around is to create an output log file:

```
cat("", file="log.txt")
testfn <- function() cat("hello from", i, "\n", file="log.txt", append=TRUE)
foreach(i=1:n, .packages = c("tcltk", "tcltk2"), .verbose = T) %dopar% {
    tclTaskSchedule(1000, testfn(), id = paste0("task", i), redo = 10)
}
```

This can then be monitored using `tail -f log.txt` from a `bash` terminal.

Comment: Since the code uses `outfile="log.txt"`, the output from the print statements goes to log.txt without the need of modifying `testfn`.  It also catches the error messages which were key to determining the cause of the problem.

Comment: Note that foreach _does not_ create a new Rscript instance for each iteration of a loop: that would generally be horribly inefficient. With doParallel and doSNOW, you create the Rscript instances by calling makeCluster and those "workers" will repeatedly execute tasks coming from potentially many foreach loops.